# How to pass iframe data to parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

In a iframe div, I have several pages. whenever user scrolls within that div, I need to update the current page number in parent window (same origin).

To achieve this, I have binded a scroll event to the div element and made the calculations to get current page number in iframe. But, struck how to pass this data to parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function in your parent page.

**Parent**

```
function parentcalc(data)
{
 //use your data
}
```

And call this function in the child like this

**iframe**

```
parent.parentcalc(mydata);
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexis! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent frame through the `parent` global variable.